# Amazon Keyspace (Cassandra) query no node was available to execute query

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, cassandra, flink-streaming, amazon-keyspaces

I'm using AWS Keyspace (Cassandra 3.11.2) run on Apache Flink in AWS EMR. Some time below query throws Exception. The same code used on AWS Lambda also had the same Exception NoHost. What did I do wrong?

```
String query = "INSERT INTO TEST (field1, field2) VALUES(?, ?)";
PreparedStatement prepared = CassandraConnector.prepare(query);
int i = 0;
BoundStatement bound = prepared.bind().setString(i++, "Field1").setString(i++, "Field2")
                    .setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.LOCAL_QUORUM);
ResultSet rs = CassandraConnector.execute(bound);
```

```
 at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.NoNodeAvailableException.copy(NoNodeAvailableException.java:40)
 at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.util.concurrent.CompletableFutures.getUninterruptibly(CompletableFutures.java:149)
 at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestSyncProcessor.process(CqlRequestSyncProcessor.java:53)
 at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.cql.CqlRequestSyncProcessor.process(CqlRequestSyncProcessor.java:30)
 at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.session.DefaultSession.execute(DefaultSession.java:230)
 at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.cql.SyncCqlSession.execute(SyncCqlSession.java:53)
 at com.test.manager.connectors.CassandraConnector.execute(CassandraConnector.java:16)
 at com.test.repository.impl.BackupRepositoryImpl.insert(BackupRepositoryImpl.java:36)
 at com.test.service.impl.BackupServiceImpl.insert(BackupServiceImpl.java:18)
 at com.test.flink.function.AsyncBackupFunction.processMessage(AsyncBackupFunction.java:78)
 at com.test.flink.function.AsyncBackupFunction.lambda$asyncInvoke$0(AsyncBackupFunction.java:35)
 at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1604)
 at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1596)
 at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:289)
 at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1056)
 at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1692)
 at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:157)
```

This is my code:

CassandraConnector.java:
Because cost of init preparedStatement is huge, I'm cached this.

```
public class CassandraConnector {
    private static final ConcurrentHashMap<String, PreparedStatement> preparedStatementCache = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, PreparedStatement>();

    public static ResultSet execute(BoundStatement bound) {
        CqlSession session = CassandraManager.getSessionInstance();
        return session.execute(bound);
    }

    public static ResultSet execute(String query) {
        CqlSession session = CassandraManager.getSessionInstance();
        return session.execute(query);
    }

    public static PreparedStatement prepare(String query) {
        PreparedStatement result = preparedStatementCache.get(query);
        if (result == null) {
            CqlSession session = CassandraManager.getSessionInstance();
            result = session.prepare(query);
            preparedStatementCache.putIfAbsent(query, result);
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

CassandraManager.java:
I'm using singleton double-check locking for session object.

```
public class CassandraManager {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CassandraManager.class);
    private static final String SSL_CASSANDRA_PASSWORD = "password";
    private static volatile CqlSession session;

    static {
        try {
            initSession();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error CassandraManager getSessionInstance", e);
        }
    }

    private static void initSession() {
        List<InetSocketAddress> contactPoints = Collections.singletonList(InetSocketAddress.createUnresolved(
                "cassandra.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com", 9142));
        DriverConfigLoader loader = DriverConfigLoader.fromClasspath("application.conf");

        Long start = BaseHelper.getTime();
        session = CqlSession.builder().addContactPoints(contactPoints).withConfigLoader(loader)
                .withAuthCredentials(AppUtil.getProperty("cassandra.username"),
                        AppUtil.getProperty("cassandra.password"))
                .withSslContext(getSSLContext()).withLocalDatacenter("ap-southeast-1")
                .withKeyspace(AppUtil.getProperty("cassandra.keyspace")).build();
        logger.info("End connect: " + (new Date().getTime() - start));

    }

    public static CqlSession getSessionInstance() {
        if (session == null || session.isClosed()) {
            synchronized (CassandraManager.class) {
                if (session == null || session.isClosed()) {
                    initSession();
                }
            }
        }

        return session;
    }

    public static SSLContext getSSLContext() {
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            in = CassandraManager.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("cassandra_truststore.jks");
            ks.load(in, SSL_CASSANDRA_PASSWORD.toCharArray());
            TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            tmf.init(ks);

            SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            ctx.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
            return ctx;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error CassandraConnector getSSLContext", e);
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    logger.error("", e);
                }
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

application.conf

```
datastax-java-driver {
  basic.request {
    timeout = 5 seconds
    consistency = LOCAL_ONE
  }
  advanced.connection {
    max-requests-per-connection = 1024
    pool {
      local.size = 1
      remote.size = 1
    }
  }
  advanced.reconnect-on-init = true
  advanced.reconnection-policy {
    class = ExponentialReconnectionPolicy
    base-delay = 1 second
    max-delay = 60 seconds
  }
  advanced.retry-policy {
    class = DefaultRetryPolicy
  }
  advanced.protocol {
    version = V4
  }

  advanced.heartbeat {
    interval = 30 seconds
    timeout = 1 second
  }

  advanced.session-leak.threshold = 8
  advanced.metadata.token-map.enabled = false
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are two scenarios where the driver would report `NoNodeAvailableException`:

1. Nodes are unresponsive/unavailable and the driver has marked all of them as down.
2. All the contact points provided are invalid.

If some inserts are working but eventually runs into `NoNodeAvailableException`, that indicates to me that the nodes are getting overloaded and eventually become unresponsive so the driver no longer picks a coordinator since they're all marked as "down".

If none of the requests work at all, it means that the contact points are unreachable or unresolvable so the driver can't connect to the cluster. Cheers!

Comment: it also makes sense to check "Caused by" - quite often this exception is a sign of problems with SSL

Comment: This time, I still connect success and query to keyspace, so I don't think all host is really down. @Erick Ramirez

Answer (score 1):

The NoHostAvailableException is a client side exception thrown by the open source driver after it has retried available hosts. The open source driver encapsulated the root cause for retry, which can be confusing.

I suggest first improving you observability by setting up these CloudWatch metrics. You can follow this prebuild CloudFormation template to get started it only takes a few seconds.

Here is a  set up for Keyspace & Table Metrics for Amazon Keyspaces using Cloud Watch:
https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-keyspaces-cloudwatch-cloudformation-templates

You can also replace retry policy with the following examples found in this helper project. The retry policy in this project will either try or throw the original exception which will remove the occurrences of NoHostAvailableException this will provide you with better transparency to your application. Here's the like to the Github repo: https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-keyspaces-java-driver-helpers

If you're using the private VPC endpoint you want to add the following permissions to enable more entries in the system.peers table.,
Amazon Keyspaces just announced new functionality that will provide more connection points when establishing a session with a private VPC endpoints.

Here is a link about how Keyspaces now automatically optimizes client connection made through AWS PrivateLink to improve availability and write and read: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2021/07/amazon-keyspaces-for-apache-cassandra-now-automatically-optimi/

This link that talks about Using Amazon Keypscaes with Interface VPC Endpoints: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/keyspaces/latest/devguide/vpc-endpoints.html . To enable this new functionality you will need to provide additional permissions to DescribeNetworkInterfaces and DescribeVpcEndpoints.

```
  {
   "Version":"2012-10-17",
   "Statement":[
      {
         "Sid":"ListVPCEndpoints",
         "Effect":"Allow",
         "Action":[
            "ec2:DescribeNetworkInterfaces",
            "ec2:DescribeVpcEndpoints"
         ],
         "Resource":"*"
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this:

```
.withLocalDatacenter(AppUtil.getProperty("cassandra.localdatacenter"))
```

Pulls back a data center name which either does not match the keyspace replication definition or the configured data center name:

```
nodetool status | grep Datacenter
```

Basically, if your connection is defined with a local data center which does not exist, it will still try to read/write with replicas in that data center.  This will fail, because it obviously cannot find nodes in a non-existent data center.

Similar question here: [NoHostAvailable error in cqlsh console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41879216/nohostavailable-error-in-cqlsh-console)

Comment: To be clear, I just edit my code, AppUtil.getProperty("cassandra.localdatacenter") = "ap-southeast-1". I still think this issue involves datacenter, I still review my code many times and correct datacenter.

Comment: @Scorpion does that match what is defined in both the keyspace definition and the Cassandra-rackdc.properties file?

Comment: As describe in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/keyspaces/latest/devguide/using_java_driver.html, local-datacenter is region. I run query select data_center from local => ap-southeast-1